# Google Sheets For Filtered Drop Down

Tags: validation, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have two sheets: CONTACTS and UPDATES.

On the CONTACTS sheet there are 2 columns: COMPANY and NAME. If I have 10 contacts at a company, then there will be 10 rows with the same company in column 1, and the names of the 10 people in column 2. Now of course there's a lot of companies and names on this list.

On the UPDATES page, column 1 is a drop down that lets me select the name of the company. In column 2 I want to have a pull down that filters and shows me only the people in the company that's in column 1.

I've searched quite a bit and while I have found things that are similar, none of the tips are quite right / work for my use case.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UNIQUE` + `FILTER` to filter the results, but that won't give you the a dropdown. For a filtered dropdown, you can use the formula to get the filtered list and then use that as your range.

For example, in your CONTACTS tab, add a new column FilteredList, with this formula in the first row:

```
=unique(filter(B:B,A:A=E1))
```

where `B:B` is the NAME column, `A:A` is the COMPANY column and `E1` is where you select the company name on the UPDATES page.

Now, instead of making the NAMES list as your valid entries, set it to FilteredList.

Comment: Thank you - this does work. It's not quite as "one-step" as I had hoped, but it gets the job done and certainly saves me the time from obsessing over this! Have a great day and thanks again!